# File Explorer Links Not Opening From SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, links

Some of our SharePoint sites have links to content on our networks shared folders.  For some users the links don't open, the browser just hangs.  This happens on SharePoint Online sites.  The same users can open similar links on our SharePoint 2010 sites.  Also, if they copy and paste the links into their browser address bar the content opens.  This seems isolated to SharePoint Online sites.  Our employees use Internet Explorer.  Any ideas what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the links of the content on our networks shared folders?

How did you add in the page in SharePoint online?

To troubleshoot the issue, you could create a new page and add the links to content on your networks shared folders.

And you also could clear IE cache to check if the same issue will occur.